# Minimum iOS version that supports c++ 0x

Tags: iphone, c++, ios, c++11

I have small game engine written in c++. I'm considering using some features of c++0x

What minimum version of ios required?  Does the new standard comes as an additional dynamic library or is it just statically linked?

Update:

I'm planning to use lambdas, new for cycle and auto type deduction

Mooing Duck:
I want both make and run.

Comment: Do you want the minimum version to _make_ C++11 programs, or to _run_ C++11 programs?  (Please put the answer in the question, not a comment)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C++11 support on iOS is pretty much restricted to the Clang compiler, which has been slowly adding C++11 features over several releases. The standard library on iOS that supports C++11 is `libc++`, and it is dynamically linked, so new features that need standard library support are going to have minimum SDK versions. It wasn't really until iOS 5 that Apple felt comfortable saying that C++11 is supported by the compiler, but some features were available before then. Ultimately, it depends on what feature you're considering, and the simplest way to find out (since I'm not aware of any laundry list of features and which versions of iOS they work on) is simply to make a small test case and try to build it against various iOS SDK versions.

Comment: Thanks I think that's the way to go.